# Jmeter while controller doesn't seem to evaluate variables as numbers

Tags: xpath, jmeter, beanshell

I am writing a jmeter script that keeps loading data until a table reaches a specified size. I have a while loop, in which I have one HTTP Sampler to loads the data, then another HTTP Sampler with an XPath Post-processor to check the table size (they call two different APIs).  The reference variable of the XPath Post Processor is currentSize and I have a user defined variable maxSize, but using ${currentSize} < ${maxSize} as the condition for the while loop creates an infinite loop.

Thinking maybe the problem is that the output of XPath is a string, I've tried doing various things in beanshell to coerce it to a number, but I'm a beanshell noob, so I haven't been successful with that either.  Can anyone guide me about how to get jmeter to recognize a variable as a number? (Preferably a decimal, but if I have to round to an int, I can live with that.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using __javascript(parseInt()) should suffice for you to check the condition.

e.g.

${__javaScript(parseInt(${time_elapsed_string}) < parseInt(${duration}))}

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted, with one tweak. I realized that the variable ${currentSize} wasn't defined until after the XPath Post Processor, which was inside the loop, so it didn't work as part of the loop definition. Once I set currentSize to 0 as a user-defined variable as well, it worked like a charm!  `${__javaScript(parseInt(${currentSize}) < parseFloat(${maxSize})*1024*1024 )}`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have following variables:

- currentSize
- maxSize
- continue

where `continue` is set via [User Defined Variables](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65146-using-user-defined-variables-in-jmeter-2-6) and has the value of `true`

You can use following Beanshell code to check if current size is equal or greater than maximum size:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

String currentSize = vars.get("currentSize");
String maxSize = vars.get("maxSize");

BigDecimal currentSizeNumber = new BigDecimal(currentSize);
BigDecimal maxSizeNumber = new BigDecimal(maxSize);

if (currentSizeNumber.compareTo(maxSizeNumber) > -1){
    vars.put("continue", "false");
}
```

Make sure that following criteria are met:

1. Your While Controller has `${continue}` as a condition
2. Beanshell Sampler, Pre / Post Processor or Assertion with the code above is added as a child of the While Controller

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details and kind of Beanshell cookbook.

Everything should work this way.

Hope this helps.